# Recover files from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I recently was using Eclipse and accidentally deleted some files.  But before I realized it I closed out Eclipse.  Now when I try to restore from local history it says no local history found.  Is there any was to find it?  I tried using Recuva to find the file also.

Answer (score 1):

not easy task if you don't have backups

Try this 2 others tools for disk recovery 
http://www.recover4all.com/
http://www.r-studio.com/Data_Recovery_Download.shtml

recovery4all is a powerful tool very light, like that you avoid rewriting your files while installing an application or so.

if the file condition is not good (in recover4all), you have less chance to get them back

if recovery fail you can try to erase your version with a frech version of eclips

there is an other possibility, "windows restore" feature but it's not guarantee as it does not create full images.